# how to use fetch row using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i do a little research and couldnt find a better solution i have this codes using codeigniter, im new to this framework

views

```
<?php 
  echo "records form database </br>";

  foreach($records as $rec){
  $recrows = array($rec->Tbprod_id,
                 $rec->Tbprod_name,
                 $rec->Tbprod_details,
                 $rec->Tbprod_details,
                 $rec->Tbprod_price,
                 $rec->Tbprod_vip,
                 $rec->Tbprod_qty,
                 $rec->Tbprod_src);

  echo $recrows[0]."  ".$recrows[1]."<br/>";
};
?>
```

pages

```
$data['records']=$this->HomeModel->productData();
```

model

```
class HomeModel extends CI_Model{
   public function productData(){
      $query = $this->db->get('products');
      return $query->result();
}
```

for me using this method, it will be more easy to transfer my work to codeigniter because i just need to put

```
<?=row[]?>
```

Comment: What's the problem/error/bug?

Comment: just do this `echo $rec->Tbprod_id` instead of pushing it into another array and then echo it in your foreach loop

Comment: @hungrykoala no error im just looking for another way to loop information on my database

Comment: @pradeep thanks it works although i need to type whole name of the field

Answer (score 0):

In view page, no need of assigning it to a new variable `$recrows`. Simple you can write `echo $rec->Tbprod_id`.

Else

```
<?php foreach($records as $rec){ ?>

  <?=$rec->Tbprod_id;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update below model code

```
class HomeModel extends CI_Model{
   public function productData(){
      $query = $this->db->get('products');
      return $query->result();
}
```

to

```
class HomeModel extends CI_Model{
   public function productData(){
      $query = $this->db->get('products');
      return $query->result_array();
}
```

Which will return you an array where each array item is a table row.

You can iterate over the array to print out the entire row or by using index as below

```
print_r($variable_name[0]);
```

or

```
foreach($variable_name as $var_name){
   print_r($var_name);
}
```